# How to design index.html file in cordova?

Tags: jquery, cordova, single-page-application

I am newbie to cordova. I understood the folder structure and build process and other things in cordova except the index.html file. My question is how should I design index.html file. How at a time one page/div can be shown ?
I am having three questions.

1. Do I need to create SPA ?
2. Can I load different html file through jquery ?
3. Creating different divs?

Sorry for being unable to make the question more clear and specific.

Comment: 1. No
2. Yes, but you can also just use hyperlinks?
3. This is not a question

Comment: @Adimeus Sorry for the stupid question. But if I can use hyperlinks does that mean the page flow (navigation from one page to another) will be almost same as normal websites? so what index.html file is mainly for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you should always use a single page application - not doing this will cause you lots of problems especially once you start using plugins which won't attach to new pages.
2. Yes, but you should keep all your HTML page templates in the www Cordova folder and load data from Ajax requests into them.  Don't fetch HTML that is part of the core UI of your application over the network.  Your application needs to be able to function when there is no network.
3. Creating different divs is a valid way of doing this, or choose one of the many JS frameworks out there that help with organizing an SPA (Angular JS, JQuery, React etc).  There are also useful UI frameworks like Ionic, Framework 7, Onsen UI, even Bootstrap.

There's many ways to build out an app depending on what frameworks you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

index.html is the first page that open in your app, you need it to tell cordova to use it as homepage.

Answer (score 1):

> index.html is the app's starting page more like a home page for a web application.

Answering to your other questions, its not mandatory to create Cordova application as a SPA. But its advisable to create it as SPA to tackle performance issues. Check out this official documentation for more info on [Cordova SPA](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/next/). Also if you wanna load any other html by default other than index.html, you can configure the same in application's config.xml as follows,

```
<content src="startPage.html"></content>
```

Ensure that startPage.html is available in project root folder. Recommend you to go through this [offical documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/) for more info.

Comment: I strongly advise (as does the official Cordova documentation) that you do use a single page application model, especially if you intend using plugins as these will get unloaded whenever you load a new page in a non-SPA Cordova app.